# How to send variable value out of the function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have defined a global variable and changing its value in a function and trying to use it in another function but output is (undefined).

Heres my code :

```
var screenWidth;
var thumbNumber;

window.onresize = function() {

    screenWidth = window.innerWidth +'px';

    if(screenWidth >= 1201 + 'px') {
        thumbNumber = 4;
    }
    else if(screenWidth <= 1200 + 'px') {
        thumbNumber = 6;

    }
}


$(function() {
    $div = null;
    $('#thumbs2').children().each(function(i) {

        if ( i % thumbNumber == 0) {
            $div = $( '<div />' );
            $div.appendTo( '#thumbs2' );
        }
        $(this).appendTo( $div );
        $(this).addClass( 'itm'+i );
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('#images2').trigger( 'slideTo', [i, 0, true] );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove `+'px'` everywhere. then call the handler defined on resize event also on domready event. otherwise `thumbnumber` won't be set

Comment: I'm guessing `thumbNumber` is `undefined` in your second function? `window.resize` is not triggered (yet) when your second function is triggered so the variable is `undefined`.

Comment: your function runs when the page loads. And your variables change when the window is resized wich occurs later.

Comment: @putvande ... you are right man. now I got my answer. I also need to run the second function on window resize.

Answer (score 0):

Here two things you need to do.

1.In `jquery` put all the code inside the `$(document).ready(){}` function is best choice. So put your calculation of `window size` code in to `$(document).ready(){}` function.

2.in if conditions you are comparing values is wrong. `if` condition don't evaluate the equations. so remove `+PX` from `if` and `else` conditions

```
$(function() {
    var screenWidth;
    var thumbNumber;

    window.onresize = function() {

        screenWidth = window.innerWidth +'px';

        if(screenWidth >= '1201px') {
            thumbNumber = 4;
        }
        else if(screenWidth <= '1200px') {
            thumbNumber = 6;

        }
    }
 });   

    $(function() {
        $div = null;
        $('#thumbs2').children().each(function(i) {

            if ( i % thumbNumber == 0) {
                $div = $( '<div />' );
                $div.appendTo( '#thumbs2' );
            }
            $(this).appendTo( $div );
            $(this).addClass( 'itm'+i );
            $(this).click(function() {
                $('#images2').trigger( 'slideTo', [i, 0, true] );
            });
        });
    });
```